# Different behaviour when ssh to Windows Cygwin server, depending on password-less or not

Tags: windows-xp, ssh

I have configured my OpenSSH server on a Windows XP system. Everything is working fine... though it is depending on the way you connect on the machine.

Details :
 - on Windows side, in a domain MYDOM, I have a user jdoe. MYDOM\jdoe is a standard user (not member of Local Administrators), member of 'Remote Desktop Users' group.
 - jdoe account is properly declared in /etc/passwd on OpenSSH server running on this machine.
 - on a Linux machine, jdoe has generated his RSA keys bundle. And added this key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the Windows machine. I have checked accessright on .ssh dir and files are set correctly.

So, now, jdoe can successfully open a ssh session from the Linux client to the Windows server, without being prompted for his password. No error message. Perfect.

If I remove the RSA keys in ~/.ssh on Linux client, then jdoe is of course being prompted for his password. And access is granted as soon as the password is correctly provided.

But there is major difference between this two access methods, that I cannot explain. And which is a source of troubles... IT SEEMS THAT IT IS NOT EXACTLY THE SAME USER who is logged on !

I explain.

When jdoe is logged with prompt-for-password method, I can see the following values for env. var. :
   USERDOMAIN=MYDOM
   USERNAME=jdoe
   LOGONSERVER=\my_ADC_server
and 'id' command returns a string which contains (among other things) :
   555 (Remote Desktop Users)

When jdoe is logged with password-less method, the values are different :
   USERDOMAIN=NT AUTHORITY
   USERNAME=SYSTEM
   LOGONSERVER is not available
and 'id' content is exactly the same than previously WITHOUT the 555 (Remote Desktop Users) entry, of course.

I am puzzled. Any idea how to fix this ? How to make password-less ssh running correctly ?

Regards.